# Place Pushpin on Single Click

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, bing-maps

I'm trying to find what mouse event I should use to place a `Pushpin` on a single click. I've tried using the `MouseUp` event but that event fires even when I just click-and-drag. Is there a way to have `MouseUp` fire only on clicks and not click-and-drags? Or is there another Mouse event that I should be looking at?

Clarification: I am working with the Bing Maps WPF control, not AJAX or Silverlight.

Comment: Have a timer that runs every time the mouse is moved. Then when the timer has finished, accept MouseUp events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to hack this together by handling the `MouseLeftButtonDown` and `MouseLeftButtonUp` events.

```
private void map_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    clickTimer.Start();
}

private void map_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    clickTimer.Stop();

    if (clickTimer.ElapsedMilliseconds < arbitraryConstant) // I find that 100 works well
    {
        Point mousePosition = e.GetPosition(this);
        Location pinLocation = map.ViewportPointToLocation(mousePosition);

        targetPin.Location = pinLocation;

        map.Children.Add(targetPin);
    }

    clickTimer.Reset();
}
```

A `Stopwatch` object records how much time elapses between clicking down and releasing the click. This elapsed time is evaluated and determines whether or not it is a "click".

**Warning**: Remember to call `clickTimer.Reset()` or your `Stopwatch` object will continue to record clicks incrementally and only your first click (if you do not click-drag first) will trigger the `if` block.

**Warning**: Do not set `e.Handled=true`. This will prevent click-drag events and your map will not pan properly.